# Can not start ProcessPoolExecutor

Tags: python, concurrent.futures

I am trying to run the main() function using ProcessPoolExecutor but the main() function can not start. The program stop immediately and nothing happened. Where did my code go wrong?

```py
def main():
    with thread_pool as thread:
        for _ in range(threads):
            thread.submit(sussy_baka)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    host = sys.argv[1]
    port = int(sys.argv[2])
    threads = int(sys.argv[3])
    path = sys.argv[4]
    file = sys.argv[5]
    proxies = readLines(file)
    cpu_count = os.cpu_count()
    thread_pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=threads)
    process_pool = ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=cpu_count)
    with process_pool as process:
        for _ in range(cpu_count):
            process.submit(main)
```

Comment: it starts for me if I comment out the line proxies. what is your readLines function and sussy_baka? please provide more info.

Comment: This is doomed.  You are creating a thread pool in the main process, and then trying to use that thread pool in other processes.  If you really need to have a thread pool in each process, then you should create the thread pool in `main`.  The thread pools need to be local to the process.